# How do I fix an error on Heroku deploy build

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku, heroku-cli

I've run on this problem when trying to deploy an application on heroku. I've searched a bit a saw some people had this problem because of pom.xml i took the steps which were instructed and still coudln't build it.

The build problem was the following

```
Changes detected - recompiling the module! :dependency
remote:        [INFO] Compiling 37 source files with javac [debug release 11] to target/classes
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [INFO] Total time:  8.046 s
remote:        [INFO] Finished at: 2023-12-20T04:56:32Z
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project RosaAPI2: Fatal error compiling: invalid flag: --release -> [Help 1]
remote:        [ERROR]
remote:        [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
remote:        [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
remote:        [ERROR]
remote:        [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles
remote:        [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
remote:
remote:  !     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,
remote:        please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.
```

My pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>RosaAPI2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>RosaAPI2</name>
    <description>RosaAPI2</description>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.22</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>resilience4j-spring-boot3</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quickchart</groupId>
            <artifactId>QuickChart</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>1.34.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-calendar</artifactId>
            <version>v3-rev20231123-2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-auth-library-oauth2-http</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals><goal>copy-dependencies</goal></goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I've added java.runtime.version=11 to application.properties and i noticed there's an warning saying  'cannot resolve configuration property 'java.runtime.version'

If it's any use my java version:

```
openjdk 17.0.7 2023-04-18 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu17.42+19-CA (build 17.0.7+7-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu17.42+19-CA (build 17.0.7+7-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Answer (score 0):

`java.runtime.version=17` should not be added to *application.properties*, but you need to add it to the *system.properties* which should be created in the application directory.

Additionally, you may need to create also `Procfile` containing

> web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT -Dspring.profiles.active=$SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE -jar target/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar